# Temporary function object in a for loop

Tags: c++, function-object

Does the function object randomElementByWeight constructor get called for every iteration through the loop or can the compiler optimize this away somehow? I want to make sure the rand function is called for each iteration and I think it's nicer to have it in the function object constructor.

```
struct randomElementByWeight
{
    double randomNumber;

    randomElementByWeight() : randomNumber(rand() / static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX)) {}

    bool operator()(const Element& e)
    {
        if ( (randomNumber -= e.weight) <= 0.0 )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

...

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    iter = find_if(routes.begin(), routes.end(), randomElementByWeight());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does, a constructor is always called for a temporary variable. Unless the compiler knows absolutely sure there are no side-effects if ommitted it won't optimize it away.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note, the following code:

```
if ( (randomNumber -= e.weight) <= 0.0 )
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

can be abbreviated to:

```
return (randomNumber -= e.weight) <= 0.0;
```

Comment: I get a warning when I do that warning MS VS2008 C4800: 'double' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)

Comment: @ephi: Impossible, the `<=` operator yields a bool. Did you forget the parenthesis or something?

Comment: yup. I must have missed something. I tried it again and its ok